# Mysqli PHP - Display user info by id

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I need help with this code bc im new with mysqli

i made a web to search a user and press a button to go link http://www.example.com/test.php?id=16 **(16 is a example)** but this code show me all the user and information of the database and i only need the information of the user with the id=16 for example.

I have done the part where i search the username and the button to send me test.php?id=16 <- id=16 is only a example bc can be any number

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
<title>View Records</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>View Records</h1>

<p><b>View All</b></p>

<?php
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY id"))
{
// display records if there are records to display
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
// display records in a table
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

// set table headers
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
// set up a row for each record
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
// if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
else
{
echo "No results to display!";
}
}
// show an error if there is an issue with the database query
else
{
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

// close database connection
$mysqli->close();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Seriously? You haven't figured out how to add `WHERE id=16`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the condition through the query like

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE id = ".$id)) {
```

And please note that `ORDER BY` is not required here.And to prevent SQL injuctions you have to `mysqli_real_escape_string` the `GET` string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get id value in a variable.

```
$id_val = $_GET["id"];
```

And correct your sql query.

```
"SELECT * FROM players WHERE id ='".$id_val."'"
```

Comment: This will introduce possibilities for SQL injections.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Why down vote? Is there any error in my given answer?

Answer (score 0):

use where clause in the query like

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players where=".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY id"))